# Finding the maximum number

Tags: loops, while-loop, sum, max, min

Am trying to find the maximum number in the code below but I keep getting this error `'float' object is not iterable`

Can anyone, help me figure out the probelm?

```
while True:
 
    x = input('Enetr a number: ')
    if x == 'done':
        break
    try:
        x_1 = float(x)
    except:
        print('invalid')
        continue

print(max(x_1))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in `x` is a float number and not a list or an array. You can't take the maximum of a float number:

```
x = 1.0
print(max(x))

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

but using a list works for finding the maximum:

```
x = [1.0] #changed to list
print(max(x))

1.0
```

and preferably for you, finding the maximum number inside a list given by the user:

```
input_string = input("Enter a list elements separated by space ")
userList = input_string.split()
print(max(userList))
```

Comment: thanks, is there any way that user input numbers one by one(not in the list) and program tell us the max and the min after user said done?